# Can we maintain a list of useful links/info for newbies so that we can avoid simple questions being asked?

Tags: discussion

There have been a number of questions which were low quality that would've been answered by simply reading the raspberry pi page itself or using that site I keep hearing about [google](http://lmgtfy.com/). Should we not just set up a question and protect it as a wiki or put this stuff here so that there is a central repository?

There is a danger the quality of this site will deteriorate if we just repeat the obvious that is already out there as questions.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps useful links and information can be in the FAQ, but I don't agree that simple questions shouldn't be asked, as long as they're not exact duplicates.

Just because questions could be answered by reading something on the Raspberry Pi site or Googling doesn't necessarily make them bad questions - if they're well formed they provide a place for a clear answer that could help others looking for the same information. There is of course nothing wrong with providing external links to answer a question (or back up an answer.)

Of course, I don't think exact duplicates should be answered again and again, but even they have a place when they're closed in that they serve as a signpost to the point where the question has been answered.

Comment: Well it is early days but I think it is important to maintain the integrity and quality of the site and I have seen other SO sites suffer from simple questions being posted, I agree that duplicates should be closed but for this site to succeed it should attract enough expert and useful knowledge without being degraded if possible

Comment: @EdChum I agree we should have good quality expert questions as well, I just don't think simple questions should necessarily be discouraged.

Comment: well if we setup a wiki/faq with decent links then we can point questions to these and get them closed if the faq and links answer the question but there have been some questions which I think showed little effort in researching, hopefully this site will grow, I'm still waiting for delivery of mine...

Comment: [Embrace the non-googlers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers)!

Comment: @Alex I also addressed this in [this answer](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/17/46).

Answer (score 0):

From this meta question, [Embrace the non-Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5280/184498).

> So perhaps in the future, the next time somebody asks how many variables can be put on a page, we should kindly embrace them, and not send them on to Google. Stack Overflow is the ultimate destination — not Google. Sorry, Larry and Sergey.

I think we need these kinds of questions because our goal should be to become the **ultimate** resource for questions relating to the Raspberry Pi.